# Modem gives ERROR after issuing ATDTnnnnnnn

Tags: .net, vb.net, modem, at-command, serial-communication

I am attempting to call a remote modem using a local modem connected via USB. Programming language is VB.NET and I am using the `SerialPort` control to talk to the modem.

Communication is as follows:

I send:         `ATZ0[CR]`

Modem responds: `ATZ0[CR][CR][LF]OK[CR][LF]`

I then try to dial a number:

I send:         `ATDTnnnnnnnnnn[CR]` where `nnnnnnnnnn` is a valid number

The modem responds with:`ATDTnnnnnnnnnn[CR][CR][LF]ERROR[CR][LF]`

All other commands seem to work without any issues

For info the modem is a MultiTech MT5634ZBA-USB-V92

If I use hyperterminal and type the same commands in it works as expected and dials the number, so it must be something I am doing in my code, possible some setup in the `SerialPort` control

**EDIT**

I have posted my own answer on this which was to issue `AT&D0` to the modem. The above command are now working.

Comment: @Matt I have not developed w/ that modem but can you log into and get access to some logs for more detail?

Comment: @ChristopherRathermel - is there a command to access this information from the modem?

Comment: @Matt Not sure but I found a link to development manuals w/ details on the error codes here.  (hope it is the right version)

http://www.multitech.com/en_US/DOCUMENTS/Families/MultiMobileUSB/manuals.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found after many hours of experimentation that issuing a `AT&D0` (Ignore DTR Signal) command before `ATDT` has the effect that the modem no longer responds with `ERROR` but dials the remote modem as desired.

I am still a little confused why typing the commands into hyperterminal worked without having to issue `AT&D0` - does anyone know if hyperterminal is issuing commands silently?

Comment: I think this is something with Multitech modems. I have the same issue as I'm sending CMds through a micro processor instead of a term. DTR I think would effect all CMDS via serial but I'm excited to try this solution myself!

Answer (score 2):

I haven't issued AT commands for about 12 years, but what I remember was that you needed to read the manual specific to the modem because all the AT commands were different for each brand.

Often, if you had to dial out, you'd have to dial a "1" for an outside line, with a pause before you dialled the rest of the number. Frequently you'd have to have small waits in your dialling scripts between issuing commands. From memory, these were "W1", "W2" etc.

So to dial an outside line ("1") and then the phone number ("123456") you'd type something like this:

```
ATDT1W3123456[CR][LF]
```

It's been a long time since I did this :)

Also, from memory, AT&D0 was something like "reset the modem state" so we always started our scripts with that command.

Comment: The issue has nothing to do with outside line dialling (it is a direct outside line) `AT&D0` is Ignore DTR signal. "A call will continue regardless of the DTR line, and the only way to end the call is with the escape sequence, or if it gets terminated by the other side. This setting is only used if the computer equipment cannot provide or control DTR."

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to see your code to understand better the issue, but as a start, try to send

```
ATDTnnnnnnnnnn[CR][LF]
```

Comment: I tried this and it returned ERROR as well - I don't believe this is a command terminator issue

Comment: Please post your setup of the SerialPort control

Comment: I am not doing any setup as such, only what I posted in my original question. This now works after I issued the AT&D0 command.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried ending your "ATDT" just with [LF] instead of [CR]?

Comment: I tried this and it returned ERROR as well - I don't believe this is a command terminator issue

Answer (score 0):

`ATZ0` returns some stored configuration to use.
Maybe there is something that cause problems.
You can print if by command:

```
AT&V[CR]
```

Try factory reset command:

```
AT&F[CR]
```

And then:

```
ATDTnnnnn[CR]
```